# AND NOT is not working sql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I don't want  data where value =comedy and value=english 
but this query is showing data where value is english

```
else if(($_POST['genre'] == "Action")&&($_POST['language'] == "Hindi")) {
                $query = "SELECT movies.Title,movies.Description,movies.Movie_length,movies.Movie_release_date,movies.Featured_image 
                    FROM((relationship INNER JOIN category ON relationship.Category_id=category.Id) 
                    INNER JOIN movies ON relationship.Movies_id=movies.Id)   
                    WHERE NOT category.value='Comedy' AND NOT category.value='English'";
                    $search_result = filterTable($query);
```

Comment: `WHERE category.value NOT IN ('Comedy','English')` returns where both are absent

Comment: Did any of the provided solutions help?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
else if(($_POST['genre'] == "Action")&&($_POST['language'] == "Hindi")) {
            $query = "SELECT movies.Title,movies.Description,movies.Movie_length,movies.Movie_release_date,movies.Featured_image 
                FROM((relationship INNER JOIN category ON relationship.Category_id=category.Id) 
                INNER JOIN movies ON relationship.Movies_id=movies.Id)   
                WHERE category.value NOT LIKE 'Comedy' AND category.value NOT LIKE 'English'";
                $search_result = filterTable($query);
```

or:

```
else if(($_POST['genre'] == "Action")&&($_POST['language'] == "Hindi")) {
            $query = "SELECT movies.Title,movies.Description,movies.Movie_length,movies.Movie_release_date,movies.Featured_image 
                FROM((relationship INNER JOIN category ON relationship.Category_id=category.Id) 
                INNER JOIN movies ON relationship.Movies_id=movies.Id)   
                WHERE category.value NOT IN ('Comedy','English')";
                $search_result = filterTable($query);
```

Comment: but im still getting data of english ,i should match both Action AND Hindi  and not comedy and english

Comment: try this
`"WHERE ".strtoupper("category.value")." NOT IN ('COMEDY','ENGLISH')";`